# finding the average using functions in python

Tags: python

I do not understand how to find the average of two or more numbers. I tried importing the statistics library, so I could use the mean function, but something is not working.

I keep getting the error traceback most recent call last.

```
import statistics
def findAverage(avg,avg2):
    avg= int(input( 'Please enter a number'))
    avg2 = int(input('Please enter a number'))
findAverage()
average=statistics.mean()
print(average)
```

Comment: How should `statistics.mean()` know the mean of what it should calculate? Did you read its [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean)? What should *`data`* be in your case?

Comment: You didn't store values which you took from user. And it's very easy to do without statistics as it is very basic. It's good to learn concepts without packages in early stage.

Comment: `statistics.mean([avg,avg2])`. also should be inside the function

Comment: When you write `input( 'Please enter a number')`, what is the purpose of the `'Please enter a number'` part? Are you familiar with the term *argument*, as it relates to programming? Do you suppose that maybe you should have some of them in other places in your program?

Comment: For a learning perspective, I suggest starting simpler. Find the mean of hard-coded values. No functions. Just print it. Then, replace with user input. Then learn functions later

Answer (score 0):

You should have the same number of arguments when defining your function and when calling it. As well as calling the `statistics.mean` function on a list:

```
import statistics
def findAverage():
    avg1= int(input( 'Please enter a number'))
    avg2 = int(input('Please enter a number'))
    return statistics.mean([avg1, avg2])
findAverage()
```

Comment: While it's good that you know how to solve the problem, it's expected on Stack Overflow not to give direct answers to trivial or homework questions, and especially not without any explanation. Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: If you are throwing the answer at the OP, at least explain why this works so they can learn for the future

Comment: Thank you for your comment ! I'll know it for the future, I'm just starting using Stackoverflow as a contributor :)

Comment: @Lucas glad to hear it. I very strongly recommend reading through the [help] to get as much information as possible about answering (and asking) questions, and what the community expectations are. Please also visit the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq) on Meta.

Answer (score 0):

The use is `statistics.mean(list_of_values)` so

```
import statistics

def findAverage():
    avg = int(input('Please enter a number1: '))
    avg2 = int(input('Please enter a number2:'))
    return statistics.mean([avg, avg2])

average = findAverage()
print(average)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find avg of any quantity numbers using it:

```
# Python program to get average of a list 
def Average(lst): 
    return sum(lst) / len(lst) 
  
# Number List
lst = [15, 9, 55, 41, 35, 20, 62, 49] 
average = Average(lst) 
  
# Printing average of the list 
print("Average of the list =", round(average, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't even understand your code what it does?

I think you want to do this?

```
def findAverage(avg,avg2):
    
    return (avg+avg2)/2

avg= int(input( 'Please enter a number'))
avg2 = int(input('Please enter a number'))

print(findAverage(avg, avg2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Statistics.mean() takes a `list` as input data. You supply it with this data by passing the list inside the `()` after the call, such as this example:

```py
import statistics
data = [1,2,3] # a list of data

average = statistics.mean(data)
print(average)
```

Here's your fixed up example, with comments to explain what's going on:

```py
import statistics

# anything inside the brackets below is a "parameter", which is 
# information which can be passed to function when calling it. 
# since this function finds the two numbers on its own, it doesn't 
# need to be passed any information, so i've removed avg and avg2
def findAverage():
    # the two lines below for collecting numbers are perfect, 
    # and don't need to be changed
    avg = int(input( 'Please enter a number'))
    avg2 = int(input('Please enter a number'))

    # however since this is a function, we'll expect it to
    # return the average value it calculated from the user input.
    # we first put our data into a list like below:
    data = [avg, avg2]

    # then get the average by passing this data to the mean function
    average = statistics.mean(data)

    # then return this value so it can be printed out
    return average


# we can now call our function, and print the result
print(findAverage())
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you need to mention list of value to `statistics.mean([avg1,avg2])` . if you only want to find mean of two values, no need to use it. it is enough you use `(num1+num2)/2` .

```
    import statistics

    def findAverage(num1,num2):
        return statistics.mean([num1, num2])

    num1= int(input( 'Please enter a number'))
    num2= int(input('Please enter a number'))    
    result=findAverage(num1,num2)
    print(result)
```